# Typescript provide default generic type in another function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I made a wrapper function to execute sql statements and that function takes in a generic type to determine the return type. I wanted to make another wrapper function that provides a default type to my first generic function.

This is what I came up with and my question is, is this the right way to do it or can it be done easier? Or is this functionality already built into Typescript?

Here is a simplified example you can put directly in vscode in a typescript file. No need to execute the code I just want the types in the `test` function to be correct which they appear to be.

```
interface RowDataPacket {
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface FieldPacket {
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface OkPacket {
    [key: string]: any;
}

async function executeQuery<Result = RowDataPacket[]>(event?: string, query?: string, values?: any[], error?: any[])
    : Promise<[Result, FieldPacket[]]>
{
    var [rows, fields] = [[], []] as [unknown, FieldPacket[]] as [Result, FieldPacket[]];

    return [rows, fields]
}

function insertQuery<Result = OkPacket>(...params: Parameters<typeof executeQuery>) {
    return executeQuery<Result>(...params)
}

async function test() {
    // Should be of type RowDataPacket[]
    const [row] = await executeQuery();
    // Should be of type number
    const [rowNumber] = await executeQuery<number>();

    // Should be of type OkPacket
    const [insert] = await insertQuery();
    // Should be of type string
    const [insertString] = await insertQuery<string>();
}
```

The following is a my actual code to give some context:

The wrapper function with has the generic `Result` with the default generic type `RowDataPacket[]`.

```
export async function executeQuery<Result = RowDataPacket[]> (event: CompatibilityEvent, query: string, values: any[] = [], onError: ErrorEmitter)
    : Promise<[Result, FieldPacket[]]> 
{
    const connection = await getConnection();

    try {
        var [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(
            query,
            values
        ) as [unknown, FieldPacket[]] as [Result, FieldPacket[]];
    }
    catch (error) {
        // SQL error
        onError(event, error);
        return [[], []] as [unknown, FieldPacket[]] as [Result, FieldPacket[]];
    }
    
    return [rows, fields];
}
```

I know that the return type of an insert statement is `Okpacket` So i wanted to provide that type as default generic in another wrapper function.

```
export function insertQuery<Result = OkPacket>(...params: Parameters<typeof executeQuery>) {
    return executeQuery<Result>(...params);
}
```

The type coercion works because `packet` now has the type of `OkPacket` according to vscode. And `numberPacket` has the type of `number` which works as intended.

```
const [packet] = await insertQuery(event,
    "INSERT INTO table (v1, v2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    [value1, value2]
);

const [numberPacket] = await insertQuery<number>(event,
    "INSERT INTO table (v1, v2) VALUES (?, ?)",
    [value1, value2]
);
```

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] others can paste into a standalone IDE to  immediately work on it.  Right now [if I try that](https://tsplay.dev/wEPQkW) I get lots of errors, none of which seem to be what you're talking about, so I'd have to resolve those just to get to the point of starting to investigate.

Comment: I've added some code you can directly put in a ts file in vscode.